# Программа не работает на Linux

Tags: python, linux

```
# cc.py (change case) меняет раскрадку с ENG на РУС(и наоборот) посредством буфера обмена.
import pyperclip

eng_chars = "~!@#$%^&qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:\"|ZXCVBNM<>? 1234567890"
rus_chars = "ё!\"№;%:?йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ/ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ, 1234567890"


def change(s1, s2, s_main):
    s_finish = []
    for i in range(len(s_main)):
        index = s1.index(s_main[i])
        s_finish.append(s2[index])
    return ''.join(s_finish)

s = pyperclip.paste()

if s.isascii():
    print('ascii')
    s = change(eng_chars, rus_chars, s)
else:
    print('not ascii')
    s = change(rus_chars, eng_chars, s)

pyperclip.copy(s)
```

На винде все работает четко. Под линуксом(манжароГном) не работает. Что-то не так именно с работой с буфером обмена. Не получается у неё вставить полученый результат обратно.
Суть проги в том, что если случайно написал текст не на той раскладке, копируешь этот текст в буфер обмена, запускаешь программу и вставляешь из буфера уже нормальный текст.

Comment: Не вникал в код, но, по-моему, вы слишком усложняете задачу перевода `qwerty` в `йцукен`. Есть замечательные методы `str.maketrans` и `str.translate`, почитайте про них.

Comment: Дак я только начинаю изучать пайтон. Но суть то не в этом. Значение строк меняется коректно, проблема именно в записи этой строки в буфер

Comment: на линуксе 3 буфера обмена и на гноме они не синхронизированны.

Comment: @eri и как быть?(Я думал, что фишка питона в том, что он одинаково работает на любой системе)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации пишут:

> On Linux, this module makes use of the xclip or xsel commands, which
>   should come with the os. Otherwise run “sudo apt-get install xclip” or
>   “sudo apt-get install xsel” (Note: xsel does not always seem to work.)
>
> Otherwise on Linux, you will need the gtk or PyQt4 modules installed.

xclip у Вас установленна?

Comment: Я даже не знаю что это такое)

Comment: xclip установил и все заработало. Спасибо